# Error in x %||% list() : argument "p" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to get the status of over 100 sites using the httr library but i keep getting this error:

> ```
> Error in x %||% list() : argument "p" is missing, with no default.
> ```

I have a dataframe with all the site names. this is the line that's giving me the error

```
for(i in names)
{

  if(i != "")
  {
    URL <- GET(paste("http://",i,"", sep = "" ),set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L)),timeout(500))

    if(status_code(URL) == "200")
    {
      r <- "Active"
    }
    else
    {
      r <- "Not active"
    }
    r
    print(paste(i,r))
    all_stat <- rbind(all_stat,r) 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same error and found out I loaded the httr package followed by the plotly package. Both have the function config(). When you type 'config' you can see the namespace it belongs to... this should be httr. Load plotly (or whatever package the namespace says) first, then httr.

Comment: This save me hours of coding! thanks for the tip! plotly and httr needs to be declared for "config" function

Comment: or make config use the httr package  ``set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))``

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error; I fixed by removing `set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))`, but that may not work for your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can also be more specific just by adding the namespace  httr::config() within your HTTP request
I did no longer experience conflicting issues between plotly::config and httr::config  by then.